# How to parse BaseHTTPRequestHandler.path

Tags: python

I'm using Python's `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. When I implement the do_GET method I find myself parsing by hand `self.path`

`self.path` looks something like:

```
/?parameter=value&other=some
```

How should I parse it in order to get a dict like

```
{'parameter': 'value', 'other':'some'}
```

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse query string with urllib in Python 2.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769625/parse-query-string-with-urllib-in-python-2-4)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) from the `urlparse` module, but make sure you remove the "/?":

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
s = "/?parameter=value&other=some"
print parse_qs(s[2:]) # prints {'other': ['some'], 'parameter': ['value']}
```

Note that each parameter can have multiple values, so the returned dict maps each parameter name to a list of values.

Comment: in python3: `from urllib.parse import parse_qs`

Answer (score 38):

Python 2. Considering `self.path` could potentially be hierarchical, you should probably do something like the following:

```
import urlparse
o = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
urlparse.parse_qs(o.query)
```

Answer (score 30):

In case somebody needs it for Python3:

```
import urllib.parse
s = "/?parameter=value&other=some"
query = urllib.parse.urlparse(s).query
>>> 'parameter=value&other=some'
urllib.parse.parse_qs(query)
>>> {'other': ['some'], 'parameter': ['value']}
```

`urlparse` was renamed to [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) in Python3.

Comment: You might want to replace `import urllib` with `import urllib.parse` for PyCharm to recognise the function correctly, even though this is not required for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The cgi and urlparse modules have that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with cgi.FieldStorage using the instance variables that BaseHTTPRequestHandler provides:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile,
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={
            'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
            'CONTENT_TYPE': self.headers['Content-Type'],
        }
```